# How can I detect a rectangle with a certain dimensions in this picture, and compare the rectangle dimensions with predetermined dimensions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is a real image of a battery. I want to detect the smallest rectangular which contains the full battery. Why do I want this? Because I want to know the size of this rectangular so I can compare this size with predetermined dimensions. After comparing, the result has to be if this battery is an AA-battery for example. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I putted the image in grayscale, than I tried to place a rectangle over the battery and create a mask. Then I took a picture of another battery, grayscaled it and I subtracted this grayscale image from the mask.

h = imrect(gca,[134 181 207 80]); % coordinates of the rectangle
BW = im2uint8(BW);
figure; imshow(BW);

differenceImage1 = BW - OriginalImage;
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(differenceImage1);
title('Difference Image1');

After this i wanted to count the pixels that contained a number above 220, but this doesn't really work.

Comment: I really can't find anything how i can detect a distance between two points in a real image. Another thing i tried is to search for corners with detectHarrisFeatures but this method doesn't give me good points to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a bit of pre-processing to your image (threshold on a particular channel, here the green channel) and a median filter to remove unwanted background signal.

Then it's a matter of using [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?searchHighlight=regionprops) to identify objects in the image. The battery is the object with the largest area, so you can use the appropriate index from the structure returned by `regionprops` to get the size of the enclosing bounding box.

```
clear
clc

%/ Read and pre-process the image to clear unwanted signal
Im = imread('Battery.jpg');
ImBW = im2bw(Im(:,:,2),.25);
ImBW = medfilt2(ImBW,[7 7]);

%// Detect objects in cleaned image
S = regionprops(ImBW,'BoundingBox','Area');

%// Identify battery as largest object
[MaxArea,MaxIndex] = max(vertcat(S.Area));

imshow(Im,'InitialMagnification',20)

%// Display results and message
hold on

rectangle('Position',S(MaxIndex).BoundingBox,'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor','y')

Length = S(MaxIndex).BoundingBox(3);
Height = S(MaxIndex).BoundingBox(4);

message = sprintf('The height is %0.2f pixels \nand length is %0.2f pixels',Height,Length);

h = msgbox(message);
```

Cropped output:

[image]

Then you simply need to convert the pixel values into real units. I'll let that part up to you.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much! This will help me a lot!!

Comment: Another tiny question. Do you know how to do this with a black battery? Because the background is black, i can't find the right rectangle.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzgis_6_HvXWdklzMk9SYThQZDA

Comment: great you're welcome! That's weird I can't access the image you just posted. Can you upload it elsewhere?

Comment: I will try, wait a second :) Can you open this?

http://nl.tinypic.com/r/33nvl7d/8

Comment: Yes! I will give it a try a bit later today :)

Comment: wow you un-accepted the answer because I did not yet come back to your secondary question that was not mentioned at all in the first place? Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Lol Benoit? I still accept this answer, but i thought that maybe because when i un accept the answer, you will reply the other problem? I thought you forgot to answer to the other problem..  You are quick to take offence..

Comment: haha oh sorry about that; it's just that in the past it happened a few times to me that people un accepted an answer of mine after a few days of answering back and forth to secondary questions that never ended; I was afraid the same was happening again. I did sound harsh I'm sorry :)

Comment: No problem! Did you already find a solution for my other problem? :) Because i can't get it right..

Comment: Mhh I tried a few things but they were not robust enough unfortunately; the background looks very much like the black battery. I'll try other stuff when I have a minute

Comment: Ok thanks for trying! We are looking forward to a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to pay for Matlab, do it simply and for free at the commandline with ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and availble for OSX and Windows.

```
convert battery.jpg -fuzz 50% -format "%@"  info:
1474x406+653+986
```

That tells us that, if we trimmed the background off, the remaining image (i.e. your battery) would be 1474 pixels wide and 406 pixels tall and located at coordinates 653,986 with respect to the top-left corner of the image.

Or this will actually extract it:

```
convert battery.jpg -fuzz 50% -trim result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! But i want to connect my program with a microcontroller. Could i connect ImageMagick with a microcontroller?

Comment: Anything you can run Matlab on will also run ImageMagick. It is open source so you can compile it wherever you want.